# How can a student suggest changes in grading policies

Tags: grades, policy

I am taking a graduate course online in education. Though I have taken many online courses, my professor is clearly inexperienced. Like all education professors, mine writes about rubrics and standards. However, his grading contradicts the things he teaches us to do.

I am not concerned about my previous grades, but I would like him to make improvements for future grades this course. I don't want to wait for the end-of-term evaluations.

Should I politely and constructively suggest that he make some changes in his grading policies? What would be the most effective arguments to give?

Answer (score 6):

Once published, I don't see any easy way to change the grading scheme for a course "in progress."

However, if you mean to suggest how he can more appropriately grade assignments and examinations, that's a different matter. The best way to do this would be to start the conversation with a polite inquiry into why certain decisions were made.

> I'm a little bit confused about how this assignment was graded. You told us we should do X, but you did Y instead. Is Y something we should be doing instead of or in addition to X?

This initiates a conversation, rather than looking like an attack or direct criticism. It's usually a more effective strategy for achieving results, particularly when face-to-face conversation isn't possible.

Comment: How do you open dialogue in an online course?

Comment: @LN6595: You send an email, or use whatever mechanism for contacting the staff you've been given. However, instead of saying "Here's a bunch of suggestions," ask questions that will elicit responses.